# How to check the select text wrapped by a span with a specified class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a part of HTML see below.

```
 <p>
   <span class="anon-sentence" id="sentence_10">
     <span class="artemis_soa ano-addrest" data-id="10-2-34" data-tag="ADDRESS" data-entity_id="10-2-34" >ADDRESS</span>
     3200
     <span class="artemis_soa ano-email" data-id="11-10-44" data-tag="EMAIL" data-entity_id="11-10-44" >EMAIL</span>
   </span>
 </p>
```

User can select (draw or double select) the text like ADDRESS, 3200 or EMAIL. We only allow user can the plain text like 3200, if the text like ADDRESS or EMAIL has been wrapped by span with the class="artemis_soa", return back blank.

Here is my codes.

```
function funGetSelectTxt() {
    var element = '';
    if (document.selection) {
        element = document.selection.createRange().text;
    } else {
        element = document.getSelection();
    }
    var selectText = $.trim(element.toString());

    if (selectText) {
        // todo. does this selectText wrapped by a span with class="artemis_soa" ?

        if (! true) {
            return selectText;
        }

    }
    return '';
 }

 $('#extracted-text').mouseup(function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var selectText = funGetSelectTxt();
 });
```

mouseup event trigger the function funGetSelectTxt() to get the text user select. What I want is inside of the function funGetSelectTxt(), once I get the text user selected, need to check whether the text is wrapped by span with the class="artemis_soa"?

Thanks

Comment: It is not so clear what you are selecting and what do you mean to check? if you have htmlText you can check if there is a child span, will be much easier to help if you supply a working example.

Comment: `e.target.classList.contains('artemis_soa')` check this in your mouseup function